# Spots on underside of a tomato leaves

Tags: identification, tomatoes, pests

What are the white and yellow spots on the underside of tomato leaves? There are plenty of whiteflies around but I cannot see any eggs. These seem to be the immobile pupae but I am not sure about it since I see no eggs anywhere. I tried releasing ladybugs twice but they just flew away and i never saw a single one to be interested in these spots...
[image: o]